# Packaging / Mavenizing commonsware components

Tags: android, maven, commonsware-cwac

I am using merge list in my android project and up until now I have just been shoving the source into my src root with the rest of my code. However I'm not modifying anything so I figured it was time to include this stuff as libraries. I clone the first repo and:

```
$ ant
Buildfile: /Users/user/dev/projects/cwac-sacklist/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/user/dev/projects/cwac-sacklist/build.xml:49: taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Total time: 0 seconds
```

It looks like this ant script is looking for some stuff created by the "android" tool.. but I don't see any docs.. but I see the missing prop sdk.dir.. so I create that in local.properties.. but then I get:

```
/Users/user/dev/libs/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/ant/lib_rules.xml:126: Reference android.libraries.src not found.
```

What is the right way to go about packaging this stuff so I can shove it in my local maven repo? Or better yet, where can I find it pre-packaged or in an existing maven repo?

**UPDATE - 2014-07-08**

It looks like commonsware now has all this stuff in a proper repo:

from: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-sacklist

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:sacklist:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first error is a standard one, caused by a discrepancy between the build files in the repo and your version of the build tools. Simply run:

`android update project -p ...`

where `...` is the path to the project in question, to update the build files.

Your second error is solved by adding the following lines to `build.xml`, just after the `<setup/>` tag:

```
<path id="android.libraries.src"><path refid="project.libraries.src" /></path>
<path id="android.libraries.jars"><path refid="project.libraries.jars" /></path>
```

You will see those lines in the `MergeAdapter` edition of `build.xml`, though they apparently are not in the `SackOfViewsAdapter` `build.xml` file, as I have not touched that project in some time.

> Or better yet, where can I find it pre-packaged or in an existing maven repo?

If there is one, it's unofficial, as I am not a Maven user.